# Dell Vostro. Ubuntu 20.04 Touchpad. 3 xinput devices

Tags: drivers, 20.04, dell, touchpad, dell-vostro

Touchpad lagging a lot. Sometimes it doesnt work at all, but most of the time just lagging.
After several restarts or suspends - it may work fine for a while.

```
xinput --list
↳ DELL0AB4:00 27C6:0D43 Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)] 
↳ DELL0AB4:00 27C6:0D43 Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Is seems strange to have 3 types of mouse at the same time.
I tried to disable every except touchpad - but it doesnt help.
Also, a had this problem in about a 2 months ago, but after reinstalling ubuntu - problem was solved.
So, i think this is a software problem.

To install/reinstall ubuntu i use official DELL image with preinstalled drivers.
After that, i`ve never installed updates yet.

Comment: The list seems OK too me. However, can you try `sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and `sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all` ?

Comment: I dont have xserver-xorg-input-synaptics installed. Dell uses libinput by default

Comment: Install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics. Touchpad still works bad. Lagging